# Show a set is countable by establishing a bijection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

```
Show that the set
A = {n ∈ N | n is divisible by 27}
is countable by establishing a bijection between N and A.
```

Not too sure how to do this, I think that  the function would be f(n)=27n, but how would I show that's one-to-one and onto?

Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: You're on the right track.

Comment: $27n_1=27n_2\Rightarrow n_1=n_2$.  for $x\in A, 27|x, \exists k, x=27k$ so $f(k)=x$

Comment: By the way, it must be countable because it injects into $\mathbb{N}$ via the inclusion map. (Doesn't answer the question in the right way, I know.)

Comment: *Onto* is by construction. For *one-to-one*, suppose $f(m)=f(n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working correctly on the right track.Just show that whenever $f(n)=f(N)$,$n=N$.

Hint for proving that:-
Both the sets are multiples of $27.$

Comment: Right so to show that it's one to one, I can say f(m)=f(n), thus 27m=27n, therefore m=n ?

Comment: @ak1652-Yeah,correct.Accept my answer by clicking the green tickmark if it solves your problem.:-)

Comment: Thanks, but how would I go about showing that it's onto?

Comment: @ak1652-You have showed that.By definition it is enough to prove that for every element in set $n$ that passes through the input-output machine,the function,you get a unique corresponding value in set $N$..